# Excel formula to repeat an array n times, substituting text in each repeat

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula that repeats an array of cells n times, once for each line in an input, but also substitutes some of the text in each array with the text from the input. I know I can use the =SUBSTITUTE function to replace the text in an array, but I can't find how to repeat the arrays a variable number of times using VSTACK, or how to substitute different text into each repeat.

Here is the repeating section of the array (there are no headings and the blank top portion does not need to be repeated):

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BLANK | MECN H2O | 1:1 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Blank | 2 |
| SUBSTITUTE1_ STD | STD | 10:SUBSTITUTE3 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| BLANK | MECN H2O | 1:1 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Blank | 2 |
| SUBSTITUTE1 REP1 | SUBSTITUTE2_T=0 | 2:SUBSTITUTE4 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| SUBSTITUTE1 REP1 | SUBSTITUTE2_T=2 | 3:SUBSTITUTE4 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| SUBSTITUTE1 REP1 | SUBSTITUTE2_T=15 | 4:SUBSTITUTE4 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| SUBSTITUTE1 REP1 | SUBSTITUTE2_T=30 | 5:SUBSTITUTE4 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| SUBSTITUTE1 REP1 | SUBSTITUTE2_T=60 | 6:SUBSTITUTE4 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| BLANK | MECN H2O | 1:1 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Blank | 2 |
| BLANK | MECN H2O | 1:1 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Blank | 2 |
| SUBSTITUTE1 REP2 | SUBSTITUTE2_T=0 | 2:SUBSTITUTE3 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| SUBSTITUTE1 REP2 | SUBSTITUTE2_T=2 | 3:SUBSTITUTE3 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| SUBSTITUTE1 REP2 | SUBSTITUTE2_T=15 | 4:SUBSTITUTE3 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| SUBSTITUTE1 REP2 | SUBSTITUTE2_T=30 | 5:SUBSTITUTE3 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| SUBSTITUTE1 REP2 | SUBSTITUTE2_T=60 | 6:SUBSTITUTE3 | SUBSTITUTE5,Number_of_repeats+1 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |

For an input like this:

| Input1 | Input 2 | Input 3 | Input 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Text 1 | 111.1 | B1 | Text1b |
| Text2 | 222.2 | B2 | Text2b |

I would need this as the output:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BLANK | MECN H2O | 1:1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Blank | 2 |
| Text 1 STD | STD | 10:C,1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| BLANK | MECN H2O | 1:1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Blank | 2 |
| Text 1 REP1 | Text1b_T=0 | 2:B,1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text 1 REP1 | Text1b_T=2 | 3:B,1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text 1 REP1 | Text1b_T=15 | 4:B,1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text 1 REP1 | Text1b_T=30 | 5:B,1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text 1 REP1 | Text1b_T=60 | 6:B,1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| BLANK | MECN H2O | 1:1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Blank | 2 |
| BLANK | MECN H2O | 1:1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Blank | 2 |
| Text 1 REP2 | Text1b_T=0 | 2:C,1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text 1 REP2 | Text1b_T=2 | 3:C,1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text 1 REP2 | Text1b_T=15 | 4:C,1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text 1 REP2 | Text1b_T=30 | 5:C,1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text 1 REP2 | Text1b_T=60 | 6:C,1 | 1,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| BLANK | MECN H2O | 1:1 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Blank | 2 |
| Text2 STD | STD | 10:C,2 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| BLANK | MECN H2O | 1:1 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Blank | 2 |
| Text2 REP1 | Text2b_T=0 | 2:B,2 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text2 REP1 | Text2b_T=2 | 3:B,2 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text2 REP1 | Text2b_T=15 | 4:B,2 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text2 REP1 | Text2b_T=30 | 5:B,2 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text2 REP1 | Text2b_T=60 | 6:B,2 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| BLANK | MECN H2O | 1:1 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Blank | 2 |
| BLANK | MECN H2O | 1:1 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Blank | 2 |
| Text2 REP2 | Text2b_T=0 | 2:C,2 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text2 REP2 | Text2b_T=2 | 3:C,2 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text2 REP2 | Text2b_T=15 | 4:C,2 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text2 REP2 | Text2b_T=30 | 5:C,2 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |
| Text2 REP2 | Text2b_T=60 | 6:C,2 | 2,3 |  |  |  |  |  | Constant_Text | Analyte | 2 |

I would also need to be able to change a template array to add more rows and change some of the constant text values in the array, however the number of different text strings to substitute will not change.
I can't use any VBA/macros to achieve this.